# Angular: Creating dialog on component with existing constructor

Tags: angular

I have a component that includes a button to create a popup dialog. However, the component already has a constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(TestService) private testService: TestService) {

}
```

If this constructor exists, how do I create a button that triggers a dialog? Thanks so much.

Comment: There is a number of ways to create a dialog, you can try to use [ngx-bootstrap confirm window](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) for example, or customize the modals more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constructor should be the one that is containing the dialog view.
For instance according to [angular material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
```

is the constructor for the open dialog popup.

and,

```
constructor(
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

is the constructor for popup dialog view.

so try using

```
constructor(@Inject(TestService) private testService: TestService) {}
```

for popup dialog view component.

Comment: Hmm... does this mean that if I have a button that opens a dialog, the button itself should be an individual component?

Comment: No, actually the view that you need to load on button click need to be in a separate component(according to angular-material), where it is the "DialogOverviewExampleDialog" above.